# JSON request returns .txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, local-storage

I am having these difficulties with the data provided by the worldbank. When I was making data-calls everything went fine(I received valid JSON). But since I am using the projects API, a JSON request returns a .txt file.

My question is: can I interpret this .txt file with JS or jQuery? Or could I stock it in the localStorage?

An example of a project link : http://bit.ly/N8cFxO

```
{"rows":10,"os":"0","page":"1","total":"0","projects":{}}
```

(I know this link doesn't contain any projects)

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: It still looks like valid JSON to my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the jquery $.parseJSON() function to convert it to a json object.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the contents of the file make a valid JSON string, then you can parse it with no issues.

In the case of the file you linked, it is valid JSON and so usable.

Answer (score 0):

Read your .txt file from stream line by line and parse the JSONObject.

```
 URL url = new URL("Your api link");


 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(line);
    //parse your JSON data 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a local file.